# Is there a way to get the number of repositories per language using Github's API?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to use the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) to retrieve the number of repositories for each language. For example,

```
C++ 200,134
Java 175,432
C# 123,453
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only API with a filter parameter would by the [search repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) one:

```
GET /legacy/repos/search/:keyword
```

with the optional parameter [language](https://github.com/languages).

But that would returned a list of repositories on multiple page, so you would still need to make the sum yourself.

Note that very recently (as in early March, 2013), the **[API might limit the result to 1000 results only](https://twitter.com/go_nuts/status/309816657491156992)**.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15269057/399105), the [search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) will now give you the total number of results matched by your query. So you can use this to get the total number of repositories for one particular language:

```
GET /search/repositories?q=language:languagename
```

Language name is case-insentitive, must be URL-encoded, and spaces must be replaced with dashes. For example (Objective C++):

```
GET /search/repositories?q=language:objective-c%2B%2B

{
    "total_count": 2090,
    ...
```